# Create a SearchBar where after a user submits the search, display all matches (or partial matches) to that title

Tags: reactjs

My problem is, once I click the search button for an empty string, it should set the state for moviesSearched to movieTitles (the array of all movie titles). However, for some reason, it renders the last element in the array which in this case, is Ex Machina and I tried so many things to fix it but I just can't seem to find a solution. I'm guessing that the way I'm setting state in my filter with [movie] is wrong but I don't know what else to do.

```
import React from 'react';
import movies from './movieData';

const movieTitles = movies.map(movie => movie.title);
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchQuery: '',
            searchedMovies: []
        }
    }
    
    handleQuery = e => {
        this.setState({
            searchQuery: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSearch = () => {   
        if (this.state.searchQuery === '') {
            this.setState({ searchedMovies: movieTitles })
        } 

        movieTitles.filter(movie => {
        (movie.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) && 
        this.setState({ searchedMovies: [movie] });
        console.log(this.state.searchedMovies);
        });  

        this.setState({
            searchQuery: '',
        });      
        }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search for a movie.."
                name="searchQuery"
                value={this.state.searchQuery}
                onChange={this.handleQuery}
                />
                <button 
                onClick={this.handleSearch}
                >
                Search
                </button>
                <br />
                <span>{this.state.searchedMovies}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;


var movies = [
  {title: 'Mean Girls'},
  {title: 'Hackers'},
  {title: 'The Grey'},
  {title: 'Sunshine'},
  {title: 'Ex Machina'},
];

export default movies;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Well, I certainly think you've an issue with your filtering logic, after you reset the `searchedMovies` state back to the full `movieTitles` array you then run the filter. In the filter you have a side-effect that is setting the `searchedMovies` state to the currently iterated movie. Each iteration overwrites the previous state value. This is why you only see the last movie in the array, it was the last movie iterated!

```
handleSearch = () => {   
  if (this.state.searchQuery === '') {
    this.setState({ searchedMovies: movieTitles })
  } 

  movieTitles.filter(movie => {
    (movie.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) && 
    this.setState({ searchedMovies: [movie] }); // <-- overwrites previous update
    console.log(this.state.searchedMovies);
  });  

  this.setState({
    searchQuery: '',
  });      
}
```

## Solution

You should save the result of the filtering into state instead.

```
handleSearch = () => {
  const { searchQuery } = this.state;

  this.setState(
    searchedMovies: movieTitles.filter(
      movie => movie.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
    ),
    searchQuery: '',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using setState wrong way. You `filter` inside `setState` like this:

```
this.setState({
  searchedMovies: movieTitles.filter((movie) => {
    return movie.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase());
  }),
});
```